# .bat files not executing when double-clicked

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

When I click a .bat file it gives me a message: "How do you want to open this file?" [image: 1st picture for reference].

I expect a batch file to run a cmd for me, so even when I click an option to open the file with cmd it doesn't work. I tried creating a simple .bat command:

```
@echo off

title This is your first batch script!

echo Welcome to batch scripting!

pause
```

But when I do that the file itself doesn't even look like a .bat file: [image: 2nd picture for reference]

...and doesn't open cmd as it should.

I think there is something wrong with the .bat in regedit.

Comment: See if this helps>>>>https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/bat-files-do-not-run-when-double-clicked-fix-association/

Comment: @Moab Thank you for your help. If anyone else has this problem you can keep this thread open. Maybe I didn't understand people who know more about the computer language so I didn't know where to go and what to do. That's why my question looks unprofessional (but maybe this is what people are looking for (simplicity)). <3

Comment: if you rename your .bat to .cmd the same happen?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can also fix this from an elevated command prompt.

Open an elevated command prompt and type this:

```
assoc bat=batfile
ftype batfile="%1" %*
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason it did not work when I tried it manually just like you're showing. So I had to download .bat file association. Unfortunately I forgot to take screenshots.

Comment: Did you get any error messages or just didn't work?

Comment: Yes, there were messages in cmd, but I don't remember what exactly it said.

Comment: Maybe "access denied" if you didn't run from elevated command prompt

Comment: No, it was something like "missing..." or "registry does not exist".